# Angular Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, build

I tried to build my angular 5 app, but after running "ng build -prod" I got this error :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\workspace\my-app\src'
```

Then i run "./node_modules/.bin/ngc" to see the origin of the problem, and I got this message:

```
error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["node_modules","bower_components","jspm_packages"]'.
```

It's seems that there is something wrong with tsconfig.json, even though I didn't change it since my last successful build, Any reason why I'm getting this ?

Angular version: `5.0.0`

Angular/cli version `1.7.4`

Comment: A couple of things you could check which may help: 1) ensure you are not using private class properties in your templates (these should be public).  2) check that your import statements are spelled correctly and have the correct casing.

Comment: Thanks, but I should check that manually? I'm working in a big project and it's hard to check all files, and also why I'm not getting an error after launching ng serve if there is an issue with the imports ?

Comment: Can you share minimal reproduction on github?

Comment: I guess you would have to check it manually - you could start with the components you modified since your last successful build. I expect ng-serve should show you any errors with the imports, but when it comes to the casing specifically, it may not show any errors depending on your angular version. What TypeScript version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I'll see, I'm using typescript Version 2.4.2.